# can't post image description in facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I can't post in facebook feed an image with description.

here the code I given, It will share the image but , can't post description

```
NSDictionary *parameters=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:categoryname,@"category",descr,@"description",dataImage,@"picture", @"image/jpeg",@"content_type", nil];

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:parameters HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
```

**Edit**: I can post photo but, doesn't post the description.

Comment: "Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation".

Comment: You used `/feed` or `/photos`? If you've used, `/photos` you should use `message` instead of `description`(which is not a valid parameter for /photos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/me/feed` do not support the Image data. If you see the documentation ([Feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)), its written-

> The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px. See our documentation on maximizing distribution for media content for more information on sizes.

That means you have to give a valid url to the picture only.

---

As an alternative, I would recommend to use, `/me/photo` since it supports image data and I think picture is quite significant in your case, and feed shows just a small thumbnail.- You call.

More details- [Photo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)